# error when I try to open table on sql 8.0

Tags: mysql

I need to open table that represents what owner adopted what animal (the relation is one to many). I start with foreign keys and some columns but after I try to open that table, I get an error

This is the question from my test:

- Primary Key is the combination of both ​`owner_id`​ and `​pet_id`
- `owner_id`​ references ​`id` ​from the `​owner​` table.
- `pet_id`​ references ​`id` ​from the ​`pet`​ table. must be unique.
- other columns: ​`adoption_date`

This is the script I made

```
CREATE TABLE `pet shelter`.`adoption` (
  `adoption_date` INT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `owner_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `pet shelter`.`owner` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `pet_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `pet shelter`.`pet` ()
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

But I get this error:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.

...followed by:

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ')
>       REFERENCES `pet shelter`.`owner` ()
>       ON DELETE NO ACTION
>       ON UPDATE ' at line 4

Comment: I recommend you to read the CREATE TABLE documentation first: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

No parentheses after in either of the places you used them.

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
      [index_name] (col_name,...)
      reference_definition

reference_definition:
    REFERENCES tbl_name (key_part,...)
      [MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE]
      [ON DELETE reference_option]
      [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

So:

```
FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `pet shelter`.`owner` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

-->

```
FOREIGN KEY 
    REFERENCES `pet shelter`(owner)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```